# Can't read file with Cordova

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, filereader, cordova-plugin-file

I'm using cordova on ios. I have some code with jquery

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        /* Get data */
    }).fail(function() {
        /* If no internet connection */
        upload(category + '.json')
    }).always(function() {
        /* handle data */
    })

function upload(File_Name) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'Documents/' + File_Name, success, fail)
    function success(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader()

            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                console.log(e.result)
            }

            reader.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }

            reader.error = function(e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            reader.readAsText(file)
        })
    }

    function fail(e) {
        console.log('error: ' + e)
    }
}
```

When no internet connection I can't read file from storage. Function **upload** not fired.
Callback **success** and **fail** not fired too.

Comment: why not use Cordova Network information plugin (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/) to check if you are online, if not read local file something like `if ($cordovaNetwork.isOnline()) { Fetch_HTTP_DATA } else { READ LOCAL FILE}`

Comment: I get json from server, jquery getting actual data, if it's impossible I get this data from cache